# Updating SQL Temp Table

Tags: sql

I am trying to update a temp table and i am getting The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.  I know that i need to move the order by out of the inline but when i do that i get an error with my WHERE clause. Any help would be greatly apprecaited.

```
 UPDATE #tmp_work_order_completion
    SET completion_date = t.otp
    FROM (SELECT t.facility_id, t.year, t.month, 
                    SUM(CASE WHEN m.completion_date <= m.due_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as completed_on_time,
                    COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) as total_count,
                    SUM(CASE WHEN m.completion_date <= m.due_date THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/COUNT(DISTINCT m.id) as otp
            FROM #tmp_work_order_completion t
            JOIN #tmp_monthly_work_orders m
                    ON t.facility_id = m.facility_id
                    AND t.year = YEAR ( m.inserted_at)
                    AND MONTH ( m.inserted_at) <= t.month
            GROUP BY t.facility_id, t.year, t.month
            ORDER BY t.facility_id, t.year, t.month ) as t
    WHERE #tmp_work_order_completion.facility_id = t.facility_id
    AND #tmp_work_order_completion.year = t.year
    AND #tmp_work_order_completion.month = t.month
```

Comment: When you delete the ORDER BY line are you leaving the ") as t" at the end of it in your SQL statement?

Comment: Is there a unique id or primary id in #tmp_work_order_completion ?

Comment: I do leave the ") as t" and i do have a unique id and that being facility_id

Comment: What error do you get when you run the code without the ORDER BY? Please update your question with that SQL statement

Comment: I am not getting an error but it wont execute just keeps running